# Is there any way to change view frame and programmatically update constraints like in IB?

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints

If you change view frame in interface builder, you can tap on 3rd icon (or in menu - Editor/Resolve Autolayout Issues/Update Constraints) and update all constraints to fit the new frame. Is there any way to do that trick programmatically?

Example:

```
var newFrame = view.frame
newFrame.offset(dx: 20, dy: 35)
view.frame = newFrame

// Here comes required method like view.updateConstraints()
```

P.S.

I know that I can make an outlet for constraint or set new constraints, but I really need to update existing ones.

Comment: You should set IBOutlet to your constraint and change the constant, it is never a good practice to change the frame while using autolayout.

Answer (score 0):

No, but that's what `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` does when enabled, more or less. The problem is that the constraints it generates only keep the view where its frame was last set with adjustments per its autoresizing mask when the superview's bounds change.

If those constraints are suitable for your needs, you should just use that. If they're not, then you'll need to do it the way you seem to know you have to but don't want to.